# jQuery loop through possible elements to see if they exist?

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

I have some jQuery like this:

```
$('#mydiv1').css('color', 'red');
$('#mydiv2').css('color', 'blue');
$('#mydiv3').css('color', 'green');
$('#mydiv4').css('color', 'orange');
$('#mydiv5').css('color', 'purple');
```

I think it should be this, so it only acts if the element exists:

```
if ($('#mydiv1').length) {.css('color', 'red')}
if ($('#mydiv2').length) {.css('color', 'blue')}
if ($('#mydiv3').length) {.css('color', 'green')}
...
```

Is there a better way to check if the elements exist, with this naming convention? Something like a 'for each #mydiv(n) ' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking if the element exists is not necessary with jQuery. It won't do anything if no matched elements are found.

If what you want is a shorter way to apply the CSS to all IDs following that pattern, then you can do:

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('#mydiv' + (i+1)).css('color', colors[i]);
}
```

If you want to apply those colors in document order (the order the elements appear in the HTML), you can utilise jQuery's [*attribute-starts-with selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^=mydiv]').each(function (i) {
    $(this).css('color', colors[i]);
});
```

Comment: and trying and then refraining from acting on nonexistent elements doesn't add any extra strain/load time?

Comment: @nathan, technically it does, but it is far from significant. jQuery won't actually *try* to apply the CSS, the `.css()` method will realise it has nothing to work on, so it won't do anything.

Comment: great, that array or whatever, and for-var-i, is just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: is there any use in using '.length' in a loop like this? (I forgot 'length' in my original post but I just added it ..)

Comment: @nathan, nope not really. `.length` is the correct way to check if there are any elements, but you don't really need it here.

Comment: @Box9, per the api docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) the `jQuery` method will return an empty collection if no matches are found.

Comment: @Box9 I overlooked the fact that there are two Nathan's in here, and just assumed your comment was in response to my answer :)  You can disregard my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

The `jQuery` function (`$`) returns a collection of elements (never a `null` or `undefined` value), so if for a given selector the `length` of the collection is 0, the code (in your case the `.css()` call) will not be executed, or cause anything like a `null` reference exception.